# VBA debugging -- see all open DAO recordsets

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I am working on an Access 2010 database in which a DAO recordset is used to create new record.  However the code fails to ID the newly-created record -- it finds another record.

The developer was sloppy: he doesn't close recordsets.  The code loops around a few times and I'm fairly certain multiple instances of the recordset are the cause of the problem.

```
Set rsMain = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
         '      ... create new record ....
'rsMain.Close          '' not included, unfortunately
'Set rsMain = Nothing  '' not included, unfortunately
```

I want to `Stop` the code and see a list of open DAO recordsets.  How can I use the Immediate window to query for all open recordsets?  There must be a collection ready to view.

### Resolved

I accepted an answer as helpful because it did a great job addressing my post.  While I benefited, the answer I needed lay in a different direction -- VBA Object References.  See my comments under Gord's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the way you open recordsets.

"A Recordsets collection contains all open Recordset objects in a Connection or Database object."

You should save CurrentDB() into variable, in order not to loose info, since each call to it creates new Database reference.

Or declare something like this function that should replace all your CurrentDB() calls^

```
Public Function CurrDB() As Database
    Static mCurrDb As Database
    If mCurrDb Is Nothing Then
        Set mCurrDb = CurrentDb 
        Debug.Print Now, "static mCurrDB inited for ", hWndAccessApp
    End If
    Set CurrDB = mCurrDb
End Function
```

and in code from Q:

```
Set rsMain = CurrDB().OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
         '      ... create new record ....
'rsMain.Close          '' not included, unfortunately
'Set rsMain = Nothing  '' not included, unfortunately
```

and for debug output write function as:

```
Public Sub  OpenedRST()
    dim rst as DAO.Recordset

    For each rst in CurrDB().Recordsets
       debug.print rst.name
    next rst
end sub
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? It doesn't work for me. For one thing, there is no `.SQL` property in a `DAO.Recordset`. (The SQL, if any, is in the `.Name` property.)

Comment: Failure to declare the DB variable might be causing the bug.

Comment: The code now conforms to your instructions, except I am declaring the `database` object locally.  The recordset and database are cldeaned up.  The behaviour is just the same.  I don't have any reason now to think the problem is multiple instantiations of the recordset.  I guess I'll start a new post.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Locals Window.

[image: Open Locals Window]

Then you can monitor variables as you run the code.

[image: Locals Window]

Comment: Thank you, HansUp.  I almost made mention in the OP of my phobic avoidance of the Locals Window.  :-P

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where failure to use an actual `DAO.Database` object can lead to confusion. Consider the following code:

```vbs
Sub liminal()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Clients", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Debug.Print "-----"
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I set a breakpoint on the `Debug.Print` line and then run the code I can open the Watch Window to see what's going on. If I create a Watch for `CurrentDb.Recordsets` it shows nothing:

[image: noCdb.png]

but if I create a Watch for `cdb.Recordsets` I can see the Recordset I created

[image: cdb.png]

**edit re: comment**

Interestingly, a Watch on `DBEngine(0)(0).Recordsets` also shows nothing:

[image: dbe.png]

Comment: This is because: The CurrentDb method creates another instance of the current database, while the DBEngine(0)(0) syntax refers to the open copy of the current database. The CurrentDb method enables you to create more than one variable of type Database that refers to the current database.

Comment: @4dmonster Strange, but a Watch on `DBEngine(0)(0).Recordsets` also shows nothing....

Comment: Have you changed Set cdb = CurrentDb to set Set cdb = DBEngine(0)(0) ?  Or if you have kept it you should Watch on DBEngine(0)(1).Recordsets

Comment: I have missed answer update. Try to check DBEngine(0)(1).Recordsets in last case. Because call to Currentdb created new reference an it have (1) index.

Comment: I put `dao.` as a prefix on `Database`.  VBE failed to autocorrect to `DAO.`.  So I altered the library refs -- removed `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Daabase Engine Object Library` and put in 'Microsfot DAO 3.6 Object Library'.  The syntax was auto-corrected... bug stays the same... but, am I onto something?

Comment: @Smandoli I doubt that it would make any difference to the behaviour we're discussing here. You just swapped out the newer "ACE" version of DAO for the older "Jet" version. All of this stuff about DBEngine and Workspaces and Databases should behave the same.

Comment: Gord, the remedy seems to have been picking the right Object References in both the FE and BE databases, per http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/AccessReferenceErrors.html.  Your answer prompted me in the right direction.  Thanks much.

Comment: @Smandoli You're welcome. Glad to hear you got it sorted out.

Comment: @4dmonster Thanks for taking the time to explain. I understand the whole `CurrentDb` thing much better now.